# multiple tables left join returns same value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Is it possible to make a query that will return one time the value of the second table and set the otherones at NULL. Im stuck with this.

This is my query

```
return $this->db->get_results(
        "
        SELECT id, name, type, check_in_days, check_out_days, all_check_out_days, minimum_stay, maximum_stay, all_accom, GROUP_CONCAT( accom_id ) as accom, GROUP_CONCAT( seasons_id ) as seasons, conditional_type
        FROM $this->booking_rules_table
        LEFT JOIN $this->booking_rules_accom_table
        ON $this->booking_rules_table.id = $this->booking_rules_accom_table.rule_id
        LEFT JOIN $this->booking_rules_seasons_table
        ON $this->booking_rules_table.id = $this->booking_rules_seasons_table.rule_id
        GROUP BY id
        "
    , ARRAY_A );
```

This returns a array like this

```
[2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 54
                [name] => 
                [type] => minimum_stay
                [check_in_days] => 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
                [check_out_days] => 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
                [all_check_out_days] => 1
                [minimum_stay] => 0
                [maximum_stay] => 9999
                [all_accom] => 0
                [accom] => 7,7,7
                [seasons] => 1,3,4
                [conditional_type] => compulsory
            )
```

You see that [accom] is returning the 7 3 times because the [seasons] has 3 values.

can i fix this with my query or is there an other solution. I dont want to explode it and build the array again.

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT accom)`

Comment: WOW thanks a lot. A small change but a BIG HELP ;)